# How to change react-boostrap checkbox value?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
const [CheckGenderFilter, setCheckGenderValue] = React.useState(true);
```

this is the boolean,how I want.

```
<Form.Check type="checkbox" label="性別"  value={CheckGenderFilter} checked={CheckGenderFilter} onChange={(e)=>{setCheckGenderValue(e.target.checked)}} />
```

And this is the checkbox component, however when I clicked on the checkbox, nothing happened .

Comment: <input type="checkbox" checked={CheckGenderFilter} onClick={() => setCheckGenderValue(!CheckGenderFilter)} />

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it .
when I put <Form.Check> in a  <Dropdown.Item >.
There are some Mysterious Power that my checkbox not working.
Therefore I remove <Dropdown.Item >.